# How to bind lambda to hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, lambda, metaprogramming

Is it possible to implement in Ruby such behavior? (like JavaScript):

```
hash = {
  attr: 'value',
  lambda: -> do
    puts self[:attr]
    # puts @attr # or this way
  end
}

hash[:lambda].call #should print 'value'
```

Doesn't matter if it is patching or inheriting from Hash, as an accessing syntax itself. I just want make lambdas to access their parent hash without passing it on call.

Comment: `self` is a reference to the current instance, so in hash it would return the object (for ex. `main` in irb). I suggest creating a class for this.

Comment: `hash.instance_exec(&hash[:lambda])`, but why? Ruby has classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `self` - call the hash by its variable name:

```
hash = {
  attr: 'value',
  lambda: -> do
    puts hash[:attr]
  end
}

hash[:lambda].call
# value
```

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas (or for that matter, any object) have no memory of hashes that they could be a value of.

They do however remember local variables. For example if you were to write

```
def make_lambda
  hash = {attr: 'value'}
  lambda do 
    hash[:attr]
  end
end
```

Then

```
make_lambda.call
```

Would return 'value' - even though hash is no longer in scope, the lambda remembers what was in scope when it was created (it's a closure)